# Navigating to HTML page within javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, navigation, local-storage

I have this survey that stores to local storage. The user is prompted 'are you sure' once clicking submit. I'm trying to navigate to a confirmation HTML page(Confirmation.html) in my directory after user clicks 'ok' . But I'm not able to achieve both **storing values** and **navigating** to work. Can get any one only, it seems. Any help would be appreciated.

```
function clicked() {
    if (confirm('Are you sure you want to submit? You will not be able to go back.')) {
        form.submit();

    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

$('form').submit(function () {
    var person = $("#FirstName").val() + "." + $('#LastName').val();
    $('input, select, textarea').each(function () {
        var value = $(this).val(),
            name = $(this).attr('name');
        localStorage[person + "." + name] = value;
        window.location.href = "Confirmation.html";
        console.log('stored key: ' + name + ' stored value: ' + value);
    });
});
<button type="submit" value="Save" id="Save" onclick="clicked();" >Submit Form</button>
```

If the above does not show my problem, here is the whole in **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uzuj5/)**

Comment: I have moved window.location.href = "Confirmation.html" to the clicked() function but still not working entirely.

Comment: You need AJAX to submit the form data. Then redirect to the page you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
$('#Save').click(function (e) {
 if (confirm('Are you sure you want to submit? You will not be able to go back.')) {
     var person = $("#FirstName").val() + "." + $('#LastName').val();
    $('input, select, textarea').each(function () {
        var value = $(this).val(),
            name = $(this).attr('name');
        localStorage[person + "." + name] = value;
        window.location.href = "Confirmation.html";
        console.log('stored key: ' + name + ' stored value: ' + value);
    });

    }
});
});
</script>
```

and remove `onclick="clicked();"` from button.

Comment: It will navigate if nothing is filled in(skipping the required fields in  my HTML as well). filling in the fields sends to local storage but no confirmation page :( thanks though

Comment: It seems when I fill in all the 'required' fields it still sotres locally but no navigation. It works fine if some of the required fields are left blank. of course that means the required fields are not making you filll them in

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you need the **confirmation.html** page. Consider my opinions as follows:

**1st:** you are already asking the user for the confirmation giving him a messagebox. Thereafter you should only submit the form data (after any additional validation) to a **server-side page** (which I believe you have mentioned in the `action` value of the `form`).

**2nd:** If you still need the **confirmation.html** page then you should redirect to **confirmation.html** from that **server-side page** but not from your form page(the current page). Now it depends on the usage of **confirmation.html** that you should redirect to **confirmation.html** before/after feeding the form data into the database(or doing something else).

Comment: This data is all local storage if that makes a difference. Was planning on using the confirmation page as a 'trap' page to prevent the user from going back and resubmitting.